# Y-scrollbar and scrolling images to left side

Tags: css, image, scrollbar

I have two questions

1) How can I remove a y-scrollbar.

2) How can I make images scroll to the left instead of down?

Any advise? Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/rvsw0u77/1/):

**HTML**

```
<div class="ProjectGallery">
<img src="images/Thumb/10.jpg" data-title="<?=$title10?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/11.jpg" data-title="<?=$title11?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/12.jpg" data-title="<?=$title12?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/14.jpg" data-title="<?=$title14?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/15.jpg" data-title="<?=$title15?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/17.jpg" data-title="<?=$title17?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/18.jpg" data-title="<?=$title18?>"  />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ProjectGallery{height:300px;overflow:scroll;float:left;} 
.ProjectGallery img{float:left;width:100%;height:100px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="gallery-container">
            <div class="gallery">
                <div class="thumbnails">
                    <img src="images.png"/>
                    <img src="images.png"/>
                    <img src="images.png"/>
                    <img src="images.png"/>
                    <img src="images.png"/>
                    <img src="images.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        .gallery
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 120px;
            width: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }

        .thumbnails
        {
            width: 1000px;
        }

        .gallery-container img
        {
            width: 200px;
            height: auto;
        }

        .thumbnails img
        {
            width: auto;
            height: 100px;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin: 1px;
        }
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div class="ProjectGallery">
<img src="images/Thumb/10.jpg" data-title="<?=$title10?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/11.jpg" data-title="<?=$title11?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/12.jpg" data-title="<?=$title12?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/14.jpg" data-title="<?=$title14?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/15.jpg" data-title="<?=$title15?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/17.jpg" data-title="<?=$title17?>"  />
<img src="images/Thumb/18.jpg" data-title="<?=$title18?>"  />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ProjectGallery{height:300px;overflow:scroll;white-space:nowrap} 
.ProjectGallery img{width:100%;height:100px;display:inline;}
```